# Minecraft Village ID

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am wondering if there are any commands in Minecraft to change the popularity of a player with a certain village. Is there some kind of ID associated with a village. I found this mod (http://chunkbase.com/mods/village-info) that seems to show IDs of villages, so it seems like there might be some way, unless that mod assigns IDs to villages in its own code, instead of the IDs being part of the vanilla game.

Comment: You mean seeds? Persudo-random number generator seeds?

Comment: I mean some kind of command that allows you to change popularity with a certain village that would work with any village.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no commands that have direct access to village data.

You can otherwise use a third-party editor such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) to modify village files (found in `.minecraft/saves/WORLD/data/villages.dat`).

See also, [Villages.dat format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villages.dat).